# Getting returned value from a callback function -JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I know this is probably super easy. I wanna get the returned value from a callback function in an event. Code is here:

```
$('.hintItem').on('mouseenter', function(e){
     changeItemStyle(e);
     var hintItemIndex = $(this).index();
     return hintItemIndex;
});
```

I want to grab the value of hintItemIndex and store it to a new variable. Could anyone kindly help me?

Comment: That is not the way jquery callbacks work (you can't get the return value), explain your use case and perhaps we can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: What's stopping you from storing it in a variable? What does that have to do with returning a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hintItemIndex;
$('.hintItem').on('mouseenter', function(e){
     changeItemStyle(e);
     hintItemIndex = $(this).index();
});
```

Basically, you define a variable outside the fuction and assign a value to it via the function.

Comment: Beware of accessing the variable before mouseenter event occurs

Comment: True @vinayakj, I definitely agree. I didn't put that in since I thought it wasn't in the scope of the OP. Should I?

Comment: Its ok, just wanted to warn OP, as OP didnt seems much experienced about callbacks. Answer is correct & I already given +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try following function.

```
function getHintItemIndex() {
    var retVal;
    $('.hintItem').on('mouseenter', function(e){
     changeItemStyle(e);
     var hintItemIndex = $(this).index();
     return hintItemIndex;
     });
    return retval;
}

var retVal = getHintItemIndex();
```